# Determining whether something is a set and models of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In naive set theory a set is any collection of objects. Thus, something like $$\{f:V_1 \to V_2 \ | \ V_1,V_2 \ \mathrm{vector \  spaces}, f \ \mathrm{linear}\}$$ is considered to be a set. I wonder, if this is problematic and why this would actually be a set. How can I tell if something I encounter written in brackets is actually a set? Does the modeling of this set or the involved vector spaces matter and if not, why is that the case? As far as I know one can model sets in several different ways, thus having some sort of ambiguity, why is this not a problem?

Comment: I think there are two separate questions here. The ambiguity you mention is really a red herring in almost every case; usually it boils down to the fact that we have many different ways to represent ordered pairs (Kuratowski, ...) and functions (do we include the codomain explicitly or not?), but any reasonable choice is going to give the same overall picture. Basically, this is analogous to writing an algorithm in pseudocode vs. some specific programming language.

Comment: Meanwhile, in order to argue that $\{x:\mathsf{[stuff]}\}$ is or is not a set you need to use the ZFC axioms. There are a few standard tricks here; for example, on the positive side you can show that the Cartesian product of two sets is again a set and powerset and separation then let you construct things like "the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$" for given sets $A,B$, while on the negative side you can show that no set has arbitrarily large elements so something like your example is ruled out since there are arbitrarily large vector spaces.

Comment: (But of course for each *specific* vector spaces $V_1,V_2$, the class of linear maps from $V_1$ to $V_2$ is a set.) See also the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces/375762#375762). I'm leaving this as a string of comments since I'm pretty sure this has been asked here before, but tl;dr: the ZF axioms are "sufficiently coarse" that no pair of reasonable implementations of mathematics in set theory will disagree over whether something is a set.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your comments. So your 2nd comment says the example in my question would not form a set, do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is not a set. (That said, for clarity I'll reiterate my previous paranthetical: the statement "For all vector spaces $V_1,V_2$, there is a set of all linear maps $V_1\rightarrow V_2$" is true.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I will have to think about this a bit I think. Until I have read some set-theory, it appears that I need to rely on the credibility of the materials that everything they say is a set is indeed a set. This gives me a somewhat unsatisfactory feeling - guess I have to start soon.

Comment: I mean, practically every example I can think of coming from outside logic itself boils down to "first put $\{x:\mathsf{[stuff]}\}$ inside something we already know is a set (usually built via Cartesian products and powersets), then apply Separation (and don't worry about quantifying over the universe, that's fine)," and practically every non-example I can think of coming from outside logic itself boils down to "show that you can extract arbitrarily large sets from the given class via Replacement." I don't think this is too bad.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Unfortunately (perhaps fortunately?), since I don't really know what separation and classes are and what exactly it means that I can replace arbitrarily large sets via replacement I guess I will for sure have to do some reading.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different approaches to this question depending on what foundational theory you're using.

Approach 1: Material set theory

Material set theory is the most commonly used foundation of mathematics, particularly in the form of ZFC. In this approach, there is only one type of thing: a set. ZFC allows you to form sets using the following rules:

- The empty set, $\{x \mid \bot\}$, is a set [axiom of empty set]
- Given any $a, b$, the set $\{a, b\}$ is a set [axiom of pairing]
- Given any $a$, the set $\{x \mid x \in a \land \phi(x)\}$ is a set for any property $\phi$ [axiom scheme of separation]
- Given any $a$, the set $\bigcup\limits_{x \in a} x = \{y \mid \exists x \in a (y \in x)\}$ is a set [axiom of union]
- Given any $a$, the set $P(a) = \{y \mid y \subseteq a\}$ is a set [axiom of power set]
- Given any set $I$ and any indexed family $A_i|_{i \in I}$ of sets, $\{A_i \mid i \in I\}$ is a set [axiom scheme of replacement]
- $\mathbb{N}$ is a set (for a suitable specific definition of $\mathbb{N}$) [axiom of infinity]

ZFC also has two other axioms, the axiom of foundation, and the axiom of choice, which we will not discuss here. Much of mathematics can be done without the axiom of choice, and almost all mathematics can be done without foundation. The axiom of choice appears frequently enough in mathematics that it's worth understanding, but it would be too much to discuss it in this answer.

From here, it is possible to prove

- Given any set $I$ and any indexed family $A_i|_{i \in I}$ of sets, $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i = \{y \mid \exists i \in I (y \in A_i)\}$ exists [union-replacement]
- Given any set $I$ and any indexed family $A_i|_{i \in I}$ of sets, $\coprod\limits_{i \in I} A_i = \{(i, y) \mid i \in I, y \in A_i\}$ exists [coproducts]
- Given two sets $A, B$, the set $A \times B = \{(a, b) \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ exists [cartesian products]
- Given a set $I$ and any indexed family $A_i|_{i \in I}$ of sets, $\prod\limits_{i \in I} A_i = \{f \mid f$ is a function with domain $i$ such that for all $i$, $f(i) \in A_i\}$ exists [dependent products]
- Given sets $A, B$, the set $\{f \mid f : A \to B\}$ exists [functions]
- Given any set $I$ such that $\exists i (i \in I)$, and given any indexed family $A_i|_{i \in I}$, the set $\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i = \{y \mid \forall i \in I (y \in A_i)\}$ exists [intersections]
- Given two sets $A, B$, the set $A \cup B = \{y \mid y \in A \lor y \in B\}$ exists [binary union]
- Given two sets $A, B$, the set $A \cap B = \{y \mid y \in A \land y \in B\}$ exists [binary intersection]
- Given two sets $A, B$, the set $A \setminus B = \{y \mid y \in A \land y \notin B\}$ exists [set difference]
- Given a set $S$ and an equivalence relation $\sim \subseteq S^2$, the set $S / \sim$ exists, and a surjective function $\pi : S \to S / \sim$ exists such that for all $a, b \in S$, $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ if and only if $a \sim b$ [quotients]

These are all the basic tools one needs in material set theory.

Approach 2: Structural set theory

In structural set theory, there are four kinds of things: sets, elements, relations, and functions. One nice foundation for structural set theory are SEAR (short for sets, elements, and relations) which, as its name suggests, deals with sets, elements, and relations and defines functions in terms of these. Another nice foundation is ETCS (the elementary theory of the category of sets), which deals with sets and functions and then defines elements and relations in terms of these basic notions.

In structural set theory, every variable has a type. It's either a set, an element of a specific set, a relation on specific sets, or a function between specific sets. Two things can only be compared to see whether they're equal if they are (1) elements of the same set, (2) relations on the same sets, or (3) functions between the same sets. We can also never ask the question "Is it the case that $a \in A$?", since the answer to this question is either known to be yes if $a$ is given the type $a \in A$, and does not make sense otherwise. Thus, questions like "does $\mathbb{N} = \cos$" or "is $\mathbb{R}$ an element of 3?" cannot be asked in this theory, even though it's perfectly legitimate to ask these questions in ZFC. The questions don't "type-check" here.

I will give a version of ETCS here which is just as strong as ZFC (minus replacement - but replacement can be added as well if necessary). Here are the axioms:

- For any sets $A, B$ there is a set $A \times B$ whose elements can be written uniquely as $(a, b)$ for some $a \in A$, $b \in B$. [cartesian product]
- For any property $\phi(A, a)$, where $A$ is a variable representing a set and $a$ is a variable representing an element of $A$, for every set $B$, there is a set $S$, denoted as $\{b \in B \mid \phi(B, b)\}$, together with an injective function $i_S : S \to B$, such that for all $b \in B$, $\exists s \in S (i_S(s) = b) \iff \phi(B, b)$ [separation - note that often, the kind of $\phi$ which can be used here is highly restricted in structural set theory]
- Consider some property $\phi(A, B, a, b)$, where $A, B$ are set variables and $a, b$ are variables with $a \in A$, $b \in B$. For all sets $X, Y$, if $\forall x \in X \exists! y \in Y (\phi(X, Y, x, y))$, then there is a unique function $f : X \to Y$ such that $\forall x \in X (\phi(X, Y, x, f(x)))$ [function definition - again, the type of $\phi$ which can be used here is often highly restricted]
- For all sets $A, B$, there is a set $B^A$, often written suggestively as $\{f \mid f : A \to B\}$, together with a function $eval : (B^A) \times A \to B$, with the following property: for every function $f : A \to B$, there is a unique $f' \in B^A$ such that for all $a \in A$, $f(a) = eval(f', a)$. We often abusively write $f'$ as $f$ and $eval(f', a)$ as $f(a)$. [existence of function sets]
- There is a set $S$ that has two distinct elements. That is, $\exists S \exists a \in S \exists b \in S (a \neq b)$. [existence of two-element set]
- There is a set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers. This means that there is a set $\mathbb{N}$ which satisfies the Peano axioms. [axiom of infinity]
- The axiom of choice holds: if $f : A \to B$ is a surjection, there exists a function $g : B \to A$ such that $g \circ f : A \to A$ is the identity function. [choice]

From here, we can derive a bunch of other sets:

- There exists an empty set. [empty set]
- There exists a set with exactly 1 element. [one-element set]
- There exists a set with exactly 2 elements, denoted $2 = \{\top, \bot\}$. [exactly two-element set]
- For any set $A$, the set $2^A$ functions as the powerset of $A$. That is, there is a predicate $\in_A(a, S)$, where $a \in A$ and $S \in 2^S$, such that for all predicates $\phi(a)$, where $a \in A$, there exists a unique $S \in 2^A$ such that $\forall a \in A (\phi(a) \iff \in_A(a, S))$.
- For any sets $A, B$, there is a set $A \coprod B$ which contains disjoint copies of $A$ and $B$ in it. That is, there are injective functions $inl : A \to A \coprod B$, $inr : B \to A \coprod B$ such that for all $x \in A \coprod B$, either $\exists a \in A (x = inl(a))$ or $\exists b \in B (x = inr(b))$, but not both. [binary coproducts]
- Given a set $S$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$, there is a set $S / \sim$ and a surjective function $\pi : S \to S / \sim$ such that for all $a, b \in S$, $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ if and only if $a \sim b$. [quotients]
- A function $f : A \to 2^B$ represents an $A$-indexed family of subsets of $B$. We can define $\bigcup\limits_{a \in A} f(a) \in 2^B$, and we can also define $\bigcap\limits_{a \in A} f(a) \in 2^B$. We do both of these using the power-set property above, taking $\in_B(b, \bigcup\limits_{a \in A} f(a))$ if and only if $\exists a \in A (\in_B(b, f(a))$, and taking $\in_B(b, \bigcap\limits_{a \in A} f(a))$ if and only if $\forall a \in A (\in_B(b, f(a))$ [unions, intersection]

Why is replacement so tricky to formulate in this context? In ZFC, we know exactly what it means for $F(x)$ to "define a unique set". Formally, what's happening is this: we have some predicate $\phi(x, y)$, and for all $x$, there exists a unique $y$ such that $\phi(x, y)$. We then "define" $F(x)$ to be the unique $y$ such that $\phi(x, y)$.

But in out theory, we have to be careful when we talk about a "unique" set. This is because we are not allowed to even state the question of whether two sets are equal or not.

Instead, we can take a different axiom which on the surface seems very different, called "collection of sets".

- Let $\phi(A, a, C)$ be a property, where we have types $a \in A$ and $A, C$ are sets. Suppose that for all $b \in B$, there exists some $C$ such that $\phi(B, b, C)$. Then there exists sets $D, E$, together with a function $f : E \to D$ and a surjective function $g : D \to B$, such that for all $d \in D$, $\phi(B, g(d), \{e \in E \mid g(e) = d\})$.

It turns out that with collection of sets, we have access to a theory of sets which is just as strong as ZFC. In fact, each type of set theory can be interpreted in the other.

What are some advantages of structural set theory over ZFC? The main one is something called "isomorphism invariance".

When we consider two sets which have a bijection between them, we know intuitively that they should have the same structural properties. In structural set theory, it turns out that two sets which have a bijection between them are actually completely identical! We can prove that for any property $\phi(S)$, we have that for all $A, B$, if there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$, then $\phi(A) \iff \phi(B)$.

In fact, we can generalize this dramatically. Two groups (or rings or vector spaces or modules) in structural set theory are completely indistinguishable if they are isomorphic. Two topological spaces are indistinguishable if they are homeomorphic.  Two manifolds are indistinguishable if they are diffeomorphic. Two posets are indistinguishable if they are order-isomorphic.

In other words, structural set theory captures the properties of set theory that we actually care about - the ones which are preserved under structural isomorphism.

On the other hand, ZFC has some clear advantages when it comes to the construction of certain transitive models. Godel's classic proof of the relative consistency of the axiom of choice and the generalised continuum hypothesis fits much more naturally in ZFC than it does in structural set theory, though it's possible to express the construction in either case.

When it comes to the specific case of $\{f : V_1 \to V_2 \mid V_1, V_2$ vector spaces and $f$ linear$\}$, this would not form a set in either case. This is because there is no set of all vector spaces. But given two particular vector spaces $V_1, V_2$, we could (using either set theory) construct the set $\{f : V_1 \to V_2\}$ and then use separation to construct the subset $\{f : V_1 \to V_2 \mid f$ is linear$\}$.

Let's explicitly prove that there is no set $U = \{f : V_1 \to V_2 \mid V_1, V_2$ vector spaces and $f$ linear$\}$.

The first proof will be a proof in material set theory. Given a set $S$, define the vector space $V_S$ to be the zero vector space with underlying set $\{S\}$.

Then there is exactly one linear map $f : V_S \to V_S$ defined by $f(S) = S$. In particular, we have $f = \{(S, S)\}$.

Consider the set $Q = \{f : V_S \to V_S \mid S$ a set, $f$ a linear map$\}$, which is clearly a subset of $U$ and thus exists by separation. This set is exactly $Q = \{\{(S, S)\} \mid S$ a set$\}$. Now for all $q \in Q$, there is a unique $S$ such that $q = \{(S, S)\}$, so by replacement, the set $\{S \mid S$ a set$\}$ exists. But there is no set of all sets, by Russell's Paradox. Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! What would be the reason that the set I gave in the example is not a set? Do I have to check all options you gave and see that it does not have those properties or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @MaxH See the very end of the edited answer.